# How to display the number of active offers for each day of 2020? SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, count, recursive-query

The OFFERS table contains information about loan offers of bank clients. Each offer has an identifier `(offer_id), start_date, expiration_date`. The offer is considered valid on date `dt` if `dt` is between `start_date` and `end_date` for this offers.

How to display the number of active offers for each day of 2020?
Data looks like:

> ```
> offer_id start_date  end_date
> 123      2020-05-01  2020-05-17
> 5432     2020-12-01  2020-09-19
> ```

Comment: SQLite or Oracle? Please tag only one database.

Comment: SQLite, changed

Answer (score 0):

One option generates all days of the year with a recursive query, then brings the table with a `left join`.

In SQLite:

```
with recursive dates as (
    select '2020-01-01' dt
    union all
    select date(dt, '1 day') from dates where date(dt, '1 day') < '2021-01-01'
)
select d.dt, count(o.offer_id) cnt_active_offers
from dates d
left join offers o on d.dt between o.start_date and o.end_date
group by d.dt
```